# Prevent filter_xss from stripping facebook-namespaced tags

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

One of my modules uses `filter_xss` to strip tags, and I have set "fb:profile-pic" as an allowed tag. However, filter_xss won't allow any tags with namespaces (and thus colons).

Is there any way around this? Or is this a bug in filter_xss, not correctly recognizing the colon as part of the tag name?

Comment: [It's a bug](http://drupal.org/node/1328768) I'm afraid, reported in November 2011. Looks like it's currently unassigned so no hints as to when/if it will be fixed :(

Comment: Just noticed you may have actually commented on that very post, if you look at [`filter_xss()` for Drupal 6](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--filter--filter.module/function/filter_xss/6) and [`filter_xss()` for Drupal 7](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/filter_xss/7) you'll see they're identical so the problem would still have existed back in Drupal 6

Comment: Thanks Clive. I'll have to hack-ily work-around for now.

Answer (score 1):

So not a perfect "answer", but I got around the problem by (gasp!) patching core. In modules/filter/filter.module, line 1059:

```
if (!preg_match('%^(?:<\s*(/\s*)?([a-zA-Z0-9:-]+)([^>]*)>?|(<!--.*?-->))$%', $string, $matches)) {
                                            ^^
                                            Added colon and hypen here.
```

I added colons and hypens as allowed characters in tags, along with "a-zA-Z0-9". Now just have to remember to apply this patch after all core updates.